# direction of arrows in TF explanations

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has come to my attention that the direction of arrows in TF-explaining text in the ROS wiki is not consistent. As far as my knowledge goes, there is a big difference between a TF from A to B (A → B) and from B to A (B → A)

In the rqt_tf_tree things look quite simple: parent → child. It would result in things like "base_link" → "left_wheel_link" etc. So the position and orientation of a child frame is descibed within the reference frame of it's parent. My odometry node broadcasts the position of the base in relation to a virtual 'odom' frame, so: odom → base
In the wiki page for gmapping at 4.1.6 it notes: map → odom, which is consistent with the above I guess, because the total tree would be: map → odom → base

But in the wiki page for AMCL this becomes very confusing for me: quote: It... "publishes the transform from odom (which can be remapped via the ~odom_frame_id parameter) to map." And all images explaining the AMCL tranforms in this page point the other way: child → parent. I can understand why you would think this is better, but it's confusing and not consistent with rqt_tf_tree.

So what is the convention here? Or is there some sort of nuance I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277875/direction-of-arrows-in-tf-explanations/) by [geervw](https://answers.ros.org/users/31105/geervw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general transforms don't have direction so representing them with arrows is not standardized. The particular level of ambiguity is that the transform for coordinate frame A -> coordinate frame B is the inverse of what it would take to transform a point in A to be a point in B. This is why the API all use `source` and `target` frames to specify that the API is referring to changing a reference frame.

When computing the transforms to publish it's more common to think about the transforms between the coordinate frames themselves and thus think about the inverse of what a lookup call will return.

So long story short it would make sense to turn the arrows around on the [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) page to be consistent with most representations. But you should understand that the only important thing when you draw the graph is that it's a tree with the arrows in a consistent direction. It's a bit of a [users preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549770/directed-acyclic-graph-tree-arrow-direction) which way to draw the arrows. Since most other usages are drawing them this way consistency is the main reason to pick a direction.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2